# Which is the most read journal on Buddhism?

Tags: reference-request, media

I got confused while googling about which is the most popular (widely distributed, published continuously in a large number) journal on Buddhism (or Buddhist journal). It is very obvious for the publishers to advertise their products  but I want to have an actual information so that I can get authentic knowledge as well as send my articles to them. I know that there are a number of Buddhist journals published from throughout the world but my primary concern is with academic publication. I will be grateful for every information. I have not been talking about any particular branch of Buddhism e.g. Theravada, Mahayana etc. but I want to know which is the most recognised journal as a whole; I mean an academic journal that includes all of them. I want to know in detail.

Comment: Because you mean an academic journal I guess this would be on-topic on the [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/) site. You could try a question like, "How can I find out which is the most popular journal in a given field? Specifically, in the field of Buddhism?"

Comment: This page: http://www.cbs.ugent.be/node/403

Answer (score 3):

The [Journal of Buddhist Ethics](http://blogs.dickinson.edu/buddhistethics) might be one, but Atma would not call it "Buddha Dhamma" journal; yet it is another Buddhism nourishing place with interest to put the Dhamma into the ways of thinking of people in the world, rather that otherwise.

They are for sure in line with your thoughts and intentions.

For a more or lesser traditional place it might be useful to get in contact with http://www.bps.lk/ which is for sure the most known one and inventor of certain "Trade on Dhamma", made it presentable even for monastics.

As for Dhamma in line of Dhamma, Atma is not aware of any journal. http://www.inquiringmind.com/ might have tried such ways, but finished its task.

For sure not a final answer but maybe it give some thoughts.

Well known university journals are maybe:

- [Numata Center for Buddhist Studies at the University of Hamburg](https://www.buddhismuskunde.uni-hamburg.de/en.html)
- [Journal of the Oxford Centre for Buddhist Studies](http://www.jocbs.org/index.php/jocbs).

German and British Scholars are historical in a strong battle in regard of Buddhist topics on [Papañca](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/papanca_en.html) and translations.